# В чем выигрыш от реализации абстрактным классом интерфейса?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

В ADO.NET есть классы, наследуются от абстрактных, а абстрактные классы в свою очередь реализуют интерфейс.

Например, есть `SqlCommand` и OleDbCommand и т п, которые расширяют абстрактный `DbCommand`, а `DbCommand` реализует интерфейс `IDbCommand`.

Короче, все наследуется от абстрактного `DbCommand`.

Почему Microsoft выбрали такую реализацию? На мой взгляд, можно было обойтись и без интерфейса.

Полиморфизма можно было бы достичь и не используя `IDbCommand`, а приводя классы к базовому типу.

Comment: Абстрактный класс и интерфейс имеют важное отличие - класс может реализовывать много интерфейсов. Не будь интерфейса я не смогу сделать свою реализацию класса, которая наследует какой то мой базовый класс, потому что множественное наследование запрещено. Так что DbCommand просто помощь в реализации

Comment: @vitidev, не. Я к тому:"Если все конкретные реализации наследуются от абстрактного класса DbCommand, то зачем нужен интерфейс? Почему нельзя было его опустить в DbCommand? Вроде, нету других классов, кроме DbCommand, которые его реализуют."

Comment: Потому что во главе дизайна стоит именно интерфейс. Только он позволяет мне создать иерархию MyDbCommand : MyDbCommandBase, IDbCommand. То есть наличие интерфейса не ограничивает меня в реализации никоим образом (нет множественного наследования). Абстрактный класс же ограничивает меня в наследовании. Так что правильнее спросить: "зачем нужен абстрактный класс, если есть интерфейс".

Answer (score 4):

Я понимаю принципы дизайна так:

Если нам нужно описать только контракт - мы выбираем интерфейс. Так мы можем дать возможность применить этот контракт не ограничивая программиста в его реализации (интерфейс не накладывает ограничений на наследование).

Если же у нас есть какой-то обязательный код (к примеру паттерн "шаблонный метод") и мы хотим **навязать** его использование - выбираем абстрактный класс. Тут программист будет вынужден наследоваться от него.

Если нет требований "навязать", то мы описываем контракт в виде интерфейса и **опционально** можем родить абстрактные класс(ы) для "boilerplate code"

Применительно к `DbCommand` - там некая реализация в виде кучи навешанных аттрибутов на свойства и прочее, что является общим для `SqlCommand` и в `OleDbCommand`, но интерфейс `IDbCommand` оставляет свободу тем, кому это не нужно.

На практике вряд ли кто-нибудь будет использовать `IDbCommand`, но для описания контракта интерфейс предпочтительнее, поэтому у нас есть интерфейс (как описание контракта) и абстрактный класс (как базовый класс позволяющий **опционально** использовать общий функционал).

ps: эти принципы для публичного кода. В своем же коде интерфейсы(абстрактные классы) стоит рождать только при нужде.